# Allocating weighted sales revenue to reporting dates

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to find a way to distribute revenue to specific dates and weight out the numbers. So that if a day falls between my two reporting days, I want it to allocate it based on the difference between the reporting days. So for example if I have reporting dates

`20/11/2017
30/11/2017
10/12/2017
20/12/2017`

and sale dates with revenue

```
Sales dates Volumes
22/11/2017  600,000,000
12/12/2017  -100,000,000
13/12/2017  -141,400,000
20/12/2017  -100,962,000
```

I want the sale made `22/11/2017`to be distributed 8/10 to `20/11/2017`and 2/10 to `30/11/2017`and so on, so that the 4 sales would distribute to

```
Reporting dates 
20/11/2017  480,000,000
30/11/2017  120,000,000
10/12/2017  -178,980,000
20/12/2017  -163,382,000
```

I have not successfully found any solution, anyone know if I have missed something or have any good ideas how one good build such a settup?

Comment: You will probably want to include the code you are using in your question.

Comment: I don't understand how you get 10/12/2018 and 20/12/2018 numbers there...Can you be more specific?  And maybe you can add more samples here for us to understand better.

Comment: So far I'm not using any code, only showed it done with manual calculations. Since its also 10 days between reporting date 10/12 and 20/12, the 20/12 date would consist of 10/10 of -100,962,00 + 2/10 of -100,000,00 + 3/10 of -141,400,000

ian0411 - It was a typo and supposed to be 2017.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this solution uses a lot of helper columns as I haven't had time to condense it all down.  I'm sure these formula can be improved and maybe even turned into a single formula.

First step is to find the two dates that your revenue should be distributed between.
With your original data in cells **A1:B4** this formula placed in cells **C1:C4** will return the higher date:

```
=DATE(YEAR($A1),MONTH($A1),CEILING(DAY($A1),10))
```

and this, placed in **D1:D4** will return the lower date:

```
=DATE(YEAR($A1),MONTH($A1),FLOOR(DAY($A1),10))
```

**Edit:**  *After spending a bit more time awake you could replace the above two formula with* `=CEILING($A1,10)-1` *and* `=FLOOR($A1,10)-1` *respectively.*

Next we find where the sale date is in relation to the upper and lower dates.
In **E1:E4** use:

```
=(C1-A1)/10
```

and in **F1:F4**:

```
=(A1-D1)/10
```

Now to return the revenue based on that distribution:
In **G1:G4** use:

```
=E1*$B1
```

The formula in **H1:H4** differs slightly as the 100% figure should only be returned once.  The revenue for 20/12/2017 will only appear in column H.

```
=IF(F1=0,B1,F1*$B1)
```

I've placed the reporting dates in the range **J1:J4**; so 20/11/2017 in J1, 30/11/2017 in J2, etc.
The formula in **K1:K4** is:

```
=SUMIF(C$1:C$4,$J1,$H$1:$H$4)
```

The formula in **L1:L4** is:

```
=SUMIF(D$1:D$4,$J1,$G$1:$G$4)
```

Finally the formula to return your distribution will sum the previous two formula in cells **M1:M4**:

```
=SUM(K1:L1)
```

Comment: Thank you Darren! Much appreciated!